# WPF MVVM Datagrid Previous and New Values

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, datagrid, inotifypropertychanged

I am using MVVM and Behaviour for Event To Command.

I want to get the previous and current values when a DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs are passed to the ViewModel.

I cannot get the previous values, as I am using  INotifyPropertyChanged, the data is always the latest value.
Is there a way to get the previous values from and object?

Comment: Have a look at the [INotifyPropertyChanging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanging) interface... it is a complementary interface to INotifyPropertyChanged that may get you what you need.

Comment: A view model shouldn't have any dependency on `DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs` if you follow the MVVM pattern...